# Function get_next_post() not working

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I'm using get_next_post() and get_previous_post() in single.php.
But the problem is it's not displaying Next post on all single posts.
The previous post is displaying on every single page fine but next post is just displaying on first post.
Here is my code:

```
global $post;
$prevPost = get_previous_post();
$nextPost = get_next_post();
//echo 'previous <pre>';
/* echo '<pre>';
print_r($nextPost);
exit();*/
?>

<?php 
    if($prevPost) {

?>
    <div class="prev">
        <h3><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($prevPost); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($prevPost); ?></a></h3>
        <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( $prevPost->post_content , '40' ); ?></p>     
         <a class="read-more" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($prevPost); ?>">More...</a>
    </div>
<?php

    }


    if($nextPost) {

    ?>

    <div class="post-next">
        <h4><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($nextPost); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($nextPost); ?></a></h4>
        <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( $nextPost->post_content , '35' ); ?></p>

        <a class="previous" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($nextPost); ?>">More...</a>
    </div>
<?php

    } // end if
?>
```

Comment: For future reference, wordpress devlopment questions might be better suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Are you placing this code within the loop on `single.php` or outside of it? @Danimal answer below should fix your issue, but make sure to run this within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  if (!empty( $nextpost ))
```

instead of

```
   if($nextpost)
```

Comment: you may want to do that for the $prevpost too!

Comment: now it's shows nothing :( not even the previous one.

Comment: I noticed in my answer it should have been if (!empty($nextPost)) and that should have gone where your other if statement was. this is according to the documentation [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post)